# SQL Server : select where column only contains one character (but multiple times)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table like this:

```
ID     | Name   | Description
-------|--------|--------------------------------------
1      | Bob    | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
2      | Alice  | ??????????????
3      | Jeff   | ?????
4      | Drew   | Nunc iaculis lorem quis leo laoreet.
5      | John   | ???????????????????????
6      | Will   | What is your name? Is it James?
```

I want to select all rows where `Description` only contains the character `?`, but any number of times **apart from 0**.

In the example above, I would want to select the rows with ID `2`, `3` and `5`. I would **not** expect row `6` to be selected.

Comment: Mysql or SQL-Server?

Comment: Please tag your question with the correct database -- `mysql` is not the same as `sql server`.  Also, why wouldn't `jeff` and `john` be returned too?

Comment: Any repeating character or just repeating ?'s

Comment: Hit google a little bit: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49522/how-to-find-column-with-all-same-repeating-character

Comment: Sorry @jens and @sgeddes, I meant to type `mssql` but I clicked on the Stack Overflow suggestion :) I have updated it.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Just repeating `?`.

Comment: Downvoter: Any feedback about why you downvoted? Maybe you could submit an edit to my question to improve it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
WHERE table.Description NOT LIKE '%[^?]%'
```

Comment: Right, NOT LIKE, thanks

Comment: Can also add in a couple other similar statements to take into account cases specific to your task. For example, if you have rows that have `?` without being the rows you are seeking

Comment: I have done @Jackson, just made an edit :)

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from YourTable Where Description=Replicate('?',Len(Description))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Tbl
WHERE
    [Description] LIKE '%?%' AND -- For null and empty values
    REPLACE([Description],'?','') = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

For mysql  and any description length

```
select * from my_table 
where lapd('', lenght(Description),'?') ) = Description;
```

Comment: There are not only 10 `?` characters, there can be any number.

Comment: Answer updated for mysql and  .. any description length

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all question marks and then check for an empty string:

```
where length(replace(Description, '?', '')) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This will show up all entries where the first character is repeated any number of times:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100),Description VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'Bob','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.')
,(2,'Alice','??????????????')
,(3,'Jeff','?????')
,(4,'Drew','Nunc iaculis lorem quis leo laoreet.')
,(5,'John','???????????????????????');

SELECT *
FROM @tbl
WHERE REPLACE(Description,LEFT(Description,1),'')=''
```

### EDIT

As you stated in your comments later, you have to deal with the questionmark only. So you might replace the `LEFT(Description,1)` simply with `?`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do you

```
   SELECT id, Name,Description
   FROM @temp
   WHERE Description LIKE '?%' --Starts with a ?
   AND Description NOT LIKE '%[^?]%' -- Doesn't contain any other characters
```